# How to use queue at retrofit

Tags: php, android, retrofit

My PHP server script connects to hardware by RS232 so only one request will give valid feedback. How can I make sure that only one request at once will send, like a queue?

An Timer call both functions, so I see on server site 2 simultaneous requests.

```
private void deviceGetActualVolume() {
    if (isOnline()) {
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                //.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(deviceIp)
                .build();

        deviceAPI api = adapter.create(deviceAPI.class);
        api.GetActualVolume(new Callback<deviceResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(deviceResponse device_response, Response response) {
                if (!device_response.isOk()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Command Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    UpdateActualValue(0, device_response.getActualvolume());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "deviceGetActualVolume Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
        });

    } else { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.notconnected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
}

private void deviceGetScale() {
    if (isOnline()) {
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                //.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(deviceIp)
                .build();

        deviceAPI api = adapter.create(deviceAPI.class);
        api.GetScaleValue(new Callback<deviceResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(deviceResponse device_response, Response response) {
                if (!device_response.isOk()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Command Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    UpdateScaleValue(device_response.getScale());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "deviceGetScale Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    } else { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.notconnected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with retrofit and not the correct way.

Solution was to write an single background application for communicate over RS232 witch get command an variable by memcached.
The memcached is writen and read by an arrivable php component.